# Debugging values into variables or user properties

Tags: azure-data-factory

How can I spy into my values when I'm on ADF debug mode ?

I want to build a simple pipeline that digs into a storage account table. For each row, enter the value of the second column, use it to create a URL and call a web service.

I saw the output of the Lookup command but how can I saw, for example, the content of each input() into the foreach activity. Can I used the user properties for debugging reason ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When debugging, I frequently make use of the 'Set Variable' activity.  Viewing the output of a 'Set Variable' activity is spying on the value.

You want to see the input to each iteration of your ForEach.  Prepend the inner activity with a Set Variable activity.  Dynamic content `@string(item())` should be enough.